# class file for com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 not found

Tags: java, mesos

Trying to call "make" on Apache Mesos, after fixing some other javadocs related issues, this is what i'm currently getting. 
Anyone ran into the same issues?
Here is the trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac -h java/jni                \
      -classpath java/target/mesos-1.10.0.jar:/Users/hanshenriksande/Master/mesos/build/src/java/target/protobuf-java-3.5.0.jar                        \
       ../../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/MesosExecutorDriver.java
Note: ../../src/java/src/org/apache/mesos/MesosExecutorDriver.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
An exception has occurred in the compiler (12.0.2). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 not found
make[1]: *** [java/jni/org_apache_mesos_MesosExecutorDriver.h] Error 4
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need java bindings for Mesos? If not then run `--disable-java` and `--disable-python` see [auto tools options](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/2a899351641c8defb7d677bad25fe2b479d1f0b6/docs/configuration/autotools.md).
If you need this bindings then you need to downgrade your JVM to 7 or 8. Follow these [instructions](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/f99ffab06694dcfcf62bf7250c56690a25d4d912/docs/building.md)